# Linking to a CSS file in JSF?

Tags: java, css, jsf, jboss6.x

Within `<h:head/>` tags I have:

`<h:outputStylesheet name="css/common.css" />`

This is output as:

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="RES_NOT_FOUND" />`

The stylesheet is within a folder named css under the webapp folder of my maven war. When I browse to http://localhost:8080/mywar/css/common.css I see the stylesheet.

Any ideas what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-cascading-style-sheets-css-in-jsf/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I followed the directory structure and layout from tip 4 here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu1/index.html

Essentially moved the css folder to be under one called resources and then referenced it as:

`<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="common.css" />`

Now it seems to work!